# jquery function after button is click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this auto-refresh script using jquery. i want the function to run only after user had click the submit button. When user click the submit button ffmpeg will convert the video and progress.php will retrieve the estimated time taken while waiting for ffmpeg to complete converting the video.

html form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file"><span></span></label>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="videofile" />
  <br/> Please enter video title:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="videoTitle" id="videoTitle" onkeyup="check()" />
  <br />
  <input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" disabled />
</form>
```

so far i had tried this code but its not working..

```
$("#submit").submit(function(event){
$("#submit").click(function(event){
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Jquery

```
//$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#myDiv").load('progress.php')
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: as far as i know when form is submit it will automatically refresh the page. so use a form and button type submit and you are good to go

Comment: you can use `event.preventDefault()` to block form from submitting, if that is what you want.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan i think he wants to reload the page after button click not prevent it

Comment: How is the user supposed to see any of this if they just submitted a form and are being redirected?

Comment: I think you have to submit your form via ajax and display the progress of the upload on the page. After the converting is done, you can than reload your page or redirect.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: i amended my question to be more specific.

Comment: @MickJack  : your button `id` is `Submit` and not `submit`

Comment: @YoYo  wow. thank you.now my code work prefectly

Comment: @MickJack : woo ,,thats great !! you can accept my answer below..I wont mind `;)`

Answer (score 1):

***First of all*** your `button` `id` is `Submit` and not `submit` change that and check if it works

> Further if you want to run a code before submit than you can do
>   following :

use `input` `type`= `button`

and `onclick` of that run a `function`
within that `function` `submit` the form

***For eg :***

```
$('#button_id').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do whatever and submit
    $("#Form_id").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Please use this code for on click event refresh page.